# How to start a CSS animation after preloader is finished or all documents are ready with the help of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I want show a welcome message animation after preloader animation is completed. How can I do that with the help of JavaScript? How will I do that?

**Here are my HTML:**

Preloader:

```
    <div class="preloader">
        <div class="pl1">
            <div class="pl1__a"></div>
            <div class="pl1__b"></div>
            <div class="pl1__c"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Welcome Message Animation:

```
    <div class="criterion">
        <div class="text text0">W</div>
        <div class="text text1">e</div>
        <div class="text text2">l</div>
        <div class="text text3">c</div>
        <div class="text text4">o</div>
        <div class="text text5">m</div>
        <div class="text text6">e</div>
        <div class="atom atom00"></div>
        <div class="atom atom01"></div>
        <div class="atom atom02"></div>
        <div class="atom atom03"></div>
        <div class="atom atom04"></div>
        <div class="atom atom05"></div>
        <div class="atom atom06"></div>
        <div class="atom atom07"></div>
        <div class="atom atom08"></div>
        <div class="atom atom09"></div>
        <div class="atom atom010"></div>
        <div class="atom atom011"></div>
        <div class="atom atom10"></div>
        <div class="atom atom11"></div>
        <div class="atom atom12"></div>
        <div class="atom atom13"></div>
        <div class="atom atom14"></div>
        <div class="atom atom15"></div>
        <div class="atom atom16"></div>
        <div class="atom atom17"></div>
        <div class="atom atom18"></div>
        <div class="atom atom19"></div>
        <div class="atom atom110"></div>
        <div class="atom atom111"></div>
        <div class="atom atom20"></div>
        <div class="atom atom21"></div>
        <div class="atom atom22"></div>
        <div class="atom atom23"></div>
        <div class="atom atom24"></div>
        <div class="atom atom25"></div>
        <div class="atom atom26"></div>
        <div class="atom atom27"></div>
        <div class="atom atom28"></div>
        <div class="atom atom29"></div>
        <div class="atom atom210"></div>
        <div class="atom atom211"></div>
        <div class="atom atom30"></div>
        <div class="atom atom31"></div>
        <div class="atom atom32"></div>
        <div class="atom atom33"></div>
        <div class="atom atom34"></div>
        <div class="atom atom35"></div>
        <div class="atom atom36"></div>
        <div class="atom atom37"></div>
        <div class="atom atom38"></div>
        <div class="atom atom39"></div>
        <div class="atom atom310"></div>
        <div class="atom atom311"></div>
        <div class="atom atom40"></div>
        <div class="atom atom41"></div>
        <div class="atom atom42"></div>
        <div class="atom atom43"></div>
        <div class="atom atom44"></div>
        <div class="atom atom45"></div>
        <div class="atom atom46"></div>
        <div class="atom atom47"></div>
        <div class="atom atom48"></div>
        <div class="atom atom49"></div>
        <div class="atom atom410"></div>
        <div class="atom atom411"></div>
        <div class="atom atom50"></div>
        <div class="atom atom51"></div>
        <div class="atom atom52"></div>
        <div class="atom atom53"></div>
        <div class="atom atom54"></div>
        <div class="atom atom55"></div>
        <div class="atom atom56"></div>
        <div class="atom atom57"></div>
        <div class="atom atom58"></div>
        <div class="atom atom59"></div>
        <div class="atom atom510"></div>
        <div class="atom atom511"></div>
        <div class="atom atom60"></div>
        <div class="atom atom61"></div>
        <div class="atom atom62"></div>
        <div class="atom atom63"></div>
        <div class="atom atom64"></div>
        <div class="atom atom65"></div>
        <div class="atom atom66"></div>
        <div class="atom atom67"></div>
        <div class="atom atom68"></div>
        <div class="atom atom69"></div>
        <div class="atom atom610"></div>
        <div class="atom atom611"></div>
        <div class="atom atom70"></div>
        <div class="atom atom71"></div>
        <div class="atom atom72"></div>
        <div class="atom atom73"></div>
        <div class="atom atom74"></div>
        <div class="atom atom75"></div>
        <div class="atom atom76"></div>
        <div class="atom atom77"></div>
        <div class="atom atom78"></div>
        <div class="atom atom79"></div>
        <div class="atom atom710"></div>
        <div class="atom atom711"></div>
    </div>
```

**Necessary CSS are Given below in Pastebin:**

Preloader CSS:

```
.preloader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1500;
    background-color: var(--bg-black-50);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.preloader.fade-out {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
.pl1__a,
.pl1__b,
.pl1__c {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    animation: bounce1 1s linear infinite;
}

.pl1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 1.5em;
    width: 6em;
    height: 6em;
}

.pl1__a {
    background: var(--c1);
}

.pl1__b {
    background: var(--c2);
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.pl1__c {
    background: var(--c3);
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
@keyframes bounce1 {
    from,
    to {
        transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    45% {
        transform: translateY(5em) scale(1, 1);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(5em) scale(1.5, 0.5);
        animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    55% {
        transform: translateY(5em) scale(1, 1);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
}
```

Welcome Message CSS:[here](https://pastebin.pl/view/8a546387)

**The necessary JavaScript are,**

Preload JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    // Preloader
    document.querySelector(".preloader").classList.add("fade-out");
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector(".preloader").style.display = "none";
    }, 600)
})
```

Comment: I don't know how to write the JavaScript to use the animation when preloader is finished.

Comment: [HTMLElement: animationend event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) ?

Comment: Add your animation code at the end of your setTimeout call.

Comment: @WaisKamal I'm a beginner, Can you show me how will the code look like. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a div with a ID . Like, "welcome-msg":

```
<div id='welcome-msg' style='display:none'>
```

Then add this JavaScript code to your linked js file to your html

```
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(appeardiv, 1000);
    setTimeout(disappearDiv, 8000);
}
//Div will appeare after 1 sec the window is loaded fully
function appeardiv() {
    document.getElementById('welcome-msg').style.display = "block";
}}
//Div will Disappeare After 8 sec
function disappearDiv() {
    document.getElementById("welcome-msg").style.display = " none";
}
```